# Exception Value: No module named 'PIL' - in Django

Tags: python, django

Django Version: 3.1.6
Python Version: 3.6.9

I'm trying to use the ImageField in my django admin page to upload an image. When I try to upload it from my NGinx/Gunicorn server I get this error. However when I run it from port 8000 using manage.py runserver 0:8000 from the SAME server, it works. I don't understand this error. I have Pillow installed.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://54.188.59.209/admin/core/employee/add/

Django Version: 3.1.6
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1573, in _changeform_view
    form_validated = form.is_valid()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 390, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value, initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 598, in clean
    return super().clean(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 149, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 627, in to_python
    from PIL import Image

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /admin/core/employee/add/
Exception Value: No module named 'PIL'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use these Command :-

**1).** If you're using Unix then run .

> python -m pip install -U pip

**2).** This Command is for install or Upgrade setup tools. (Setup tools are install by default but you should upgrade it)

> pip install setuptools

**3).** AND now, uninstall and reinstall the `Pillow`.

*For Uninstall*

> pip uninstall pillow

*Now install*

> pip install pillow

Answer (score 0):

Pil is not available  as of now in django.
Use its successor

pip install pillow

As you said you have pillow installed then the problem must be with pip , upgrade the pip and then try out if it works .

pip install --upgrade pip

the version of pip does dictate how packages are unzipped, which ultimately determines whether or not modules are loaded properly.
Then import image and hope that works.

Comment: This causes some confusion but Pillow is just a fork of the Python Imaging Library. It has the same import as PIL because it is an open source project built on top of it.

Answer (score -2):

Django does not came with Pillow preinstalled.
To install, simply run:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

to install or upgrade.

Comment: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 627, in to_python
   `from PIL import Image` <- The error message showing django including an import of the pillow library. Django uses Pillow for image processing in ImageFields

Comment: `python -m pip install django` won't install Pillow, even if it is used for Image management,

Comment: Pillow is not installed by default but if you want to use ImageFields you will need to install it else you will get an import error from django.